# External() function missing in FileMaker 16/17

Tags: filemaker

The External ( nameOfFunction ; parameter ) function is missing in Filemaker 16/17 and the result is my TAPI plug-in stopped working

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Removed functions •The External( ) function has been removed. To use
>   functions or script steps provided by a plug-in, see Creating custom
>   plug-ins. Note  Plug-ins written for version 6.0 and earlier are no
>   longer supported.
>   [New features in FileMaker Pro 16](https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/16/fmp/en/FMP_Help/new-features.html)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me there was an architecture change in the plugins some time ago, but I don't recall the details. Have you checked out the updated plugin documentation for version 17?
It's at the bottom of this page. 
https://www.filemaker.com/support/technologies/